# How to merge perl regexp's into one combined match

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl application that gets as input two regexp's.

Is it possible to merge the regexp's into one regexp in a way that a match can only happen if the two regexp conditions are met?

Example:

```
pattern1 = "^.*$"  
pattern2 = "^abc$"
```

Outcome should be: `"^abc$"`

I know there is a module called "Regexp::Assemble" but only allows me to combine the regexp's in a way that both regexp's can create a match.

Comment: `"^.*$"` ...........

Comment: It is just an example

Answer (score 3):

You cannot merge them into a single regex - that's a much more complicated thing than you might imagine. (Outside relatively trivial cases). `regex` is a programming language, and getting something to write it for you, is a non-trivial sort of a task.

But you can test multiple regexes quite handily.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @conditions = ( qr/^.*$/, qr/[A-Z]+/, qr/123/, );

LINE: while (<DATA>) {
    foreach my $regex (@conditions) {
        next LINE unless m/$regex/;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
shouldn't match, non number
1234567
test123
Test123
```

For efficiency, you can also order the regexes so the most likely to fail come first.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but with a restriction. All you need to do is enclose one of the patterns in a lookahead assertion like so:

```
(?=pattern1)pattern2
```

This should work even if the patterns have inline modifiers (`(?i)` or similar), the first pattern's modifiers shouldn't carry over to the second pattern.

The only problem with this solution that I'm aware of are backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, etc). If there are capture groups in pattern1, then any backreferences in pattern2 will refer to the wrong group. For example:

```
pattern1 = "(a)b."
pattern2 = "a(b)\1"
text = "abb"
```

Both patterns would match `abb`, but the combined pattern `(?=(a)b.)a(b)\1` would only match `aba`.